# Как отключить PATCH запросы в Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Как известно, строка в `routes.rb` - `resources :articles` - выдаст роуты, вида:

```
GET         /articles            /articles#index       articles_path
GET         /articles/new        /articles#new         new_article_path
POST        /articles            /articles#create      articles_path
GET         /articles/:id        /articles#show        article_path(:id)
GET         /articles/:id/edit   /articles#edit        edit_article_path(:id)
PATCH/PUT   /articles/:id        /articles#update      article_path(:id)
DELETE      /articles/:id        /articles#destroy     article_path(:id)
```

1. Возможно ли в рельсах заменить PATCH-метод ТОЛЬКО put или post методом? Может, как-то отключить глобально или переключить работу с этим методом?
2. Если возможно изменить тупо роут, то каким образом можно изменить строку `resources :articles`?

Comment: PATCH-метод там не просто так стоит. Какая у вас причина, что понадобилось вдруг его отключать?

Comment: @ВиталийЕмельянцев "Политика настройки сети" внутри компании. Метод патч не доходит до сервера. Я в курсе, что такое REST, зачем там PATCH и причем тут rails - если в рельсах НЕЛЬЗЯ никоим образом заменить\переключить patch или вы не в курсе, то так и скажите!

Comment: Занимательно в этом то, что `update` из ActiveRecord следует больше семантике `PATCH`, но если его использовать со всеми (известными) полями, получится почти `PUT`. Довольно забавная ситуация.

Comment: @D-side PUT изменяет все поля. PATCH только одно. Но как методы хттп - они разные...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Да запросто.

```
resources :articles, except: :update do
  put :update, on: :member
end
```

За исключением порядка это [то же самое](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L1795), что происходит сейчас в Rails, просто в немножко другой форме: `member` является аргументом единственного роута, а не блоком-модификатором (`member do ... end`) для группы роутов.

**Всё остальное работает как обычно.**
Никаких странностей вроде другого названия параметра или подобного.

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например, так:

```
resources :articles, except: :update do
  match via: :put, action: :update
end
```

Тогда у вас будет `PUT` на `articles#update`. **Но**: параметр под ID-статьи будет называться не `params[:id]`, а `params[:article_id]`. Нужно будет учесть в контроллере.

Либо можно написать так:

```
resources :pages, except: :update do
  match ':id', via: :put, action: :update, on: :collection
end
```

Тогда у вас будет `PUT` на `articles#update` с параметром `params[:id]`. Изменения коснутся только роутов в `routes.rb`.